# How to upload data to a website on 000webhost?

Tags: web-hosting

I had designed my own autoliker script and everything is ready but I am unable to upload Zip file.

I had chosen Free web hosting service "000webhost.com", as my moto is make everything without investment.

I am unable to upload zip file on File Manager and SQL.

Can anybody tell me, How to upload my prepared zip file on database?

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote. It may have happened previous to my edit which should help. A down vote pre-edit is well understood. I thought I would up-vote to give the edit a fair start anyway.

Comment: This question isn't quite clear. You don't upload zip files to databases (normally). Are you actually trying to put a zip file into a database? Or are you trying to import data into a database and that data is in a zip file?

Comment: @JohnConde You are right about parts of this question being unclear. I agree! I read the question as being from someone who may be new to technology and unaware of the terminology and/or processes needed. This is, in part, why I edited the title. It appears to me that the OP is looking to *import* his data and is not sure how. Should we try and re-edit the question or leave it to the OP?? Cheers!!

Comment: I want to make a Facebook autoliker website.     Simply tell me steps ,I had scripts ready, just tell me free hosting service

Comment: "Tell me how" type of questions tend to be too broad. In this case, it would be. Instead, please let us know what you are familiar with and can do on your own and what specifically you need help with. For example, are you familiar with database management? Are you familiar with deploying scripts and permissions? Are you familiar with writing code? Did you write your script or did you acquire somewhere? If so, then what script and where did you gt it? The more you can tell us, the better.